# Не добавляется значение в список внутри словаря

Tags: python

Почему в данном словаре value имеет тип данных str? Хотя это список

```
   for value in dict_ZTE_GSM_GGsmRelation_index.values():
        print(value,'___', type(value))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке добавить к value как к списку ещё одно значение я получаю эрор

```
dict_ZTE_GSM_GGsmRelation_index['228_752_1'] = dict_ZTE_GSM_GGsmRelation_index.get('228_752_1', []) + [15571]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если добавить значение как str, то оно добавляется за скобками

```
dict_ZTE_GSM_GGsmRelation_index['228_752_1'] = dict_ZTE_GSM_GGsmRelation_index.get('228_752_1') + str(15571)
print(dict_ZTE_GSM_GGsmRelation_index['228_752_1'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
ZTE_GSM_GGsmRelation_index = {'228_752_1':'[1, 129, 130, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141]','228_752_2':'[1, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153]','228_752_3':'[1, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147]','228_753_1': '[1, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152]','228_753_2': '[1, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145]'}
```

Comment: так у вас же в словаре не списки а строки. вам же пишут - class 'str'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Почему в данном словаре value имеет тип данных str? **Хотя это список**

Потому что это **строка**, а не список.

Пример:

```
x = '[1, 2, 3]'
print(type(x))
# <class 'str'>
```

---

Как распарсить JSON строки в словаре:

```
import json

for k,v in ZTE_GSM_GGsmRelation_index.items():
    ZTE_GSM_GGsmRelation_index[k] = json.loads(v)
```

результат:

```
In [306]: ZTE_GSM_GGsmRelation_index
Out[306]:
{'228_752_1': [1, 129, 130, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141],
 '228_752_2': [1,
  129,
  130,
  131,
  132,
  133,
  ...
```

Comment: есть способ добавить новое значение в строку, внутрь скобок []?

Comment: @ralph_lauren, конечно есть, но нужно ли это вам?? Не лучше ли работать с реальными списками, вместо JSON строк?

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше всего преобразовать такие строки в список внутри словаря?

Comment: @ralph_lauren, можете привести в вопросе небольшой воспроизводимый пример данных в виде Python кода?

Comment: Добавил в вопрос как выглядит моя переменная, если создавать её вручную. Или вы имели введу вставить часть кода которая выше?

Comment: @ralph_lauren, дополнил ответ примером...

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё работает)